# Question about the Characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: field-theory, proof-verification, finite-fields

We can prove that any finite field of prime characteristic $p$ must have $p^n$ elements.

Conversely, let $F$ be a finite field with $p^n$ elements, where $p$ is a prime number. **Is the following argument a correct way to prove that** $F$ **has characteristic** $p$ ?

We can show, without assuming that $F$ has characteristic $p$, that every finite field with $p^n$ elements is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Therefore $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field extension and the characteristic of $E$ must equal the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_p$ which is $p$.

Comment: You say that $F$ is a splitting field of some polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ but this already includes the assumption that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a subfield of $F$, so I do not think this argument should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: said, 
$$\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{p^n}=0$$ and so

$$\underbrace{p \times  \cdots \times  p}_{n}=0$$

in a field, so $p=0$.

Comment: Would this also be correct? Since the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the order of $1$ in the additive group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and we know it must be a prime *that divides* $p^n$ (by Lagrange's Theorem), the only possible choice is $p$ ?

Comment: @Guest: Yes, it's also correct!

Answer (score 3):

The additive group of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ has order $p^n$, that is...

Comment: @orangeskid, thanks. And thanks for the correction of my typo.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
\mathbb{F}_q \subseteq \mathbb{F}
$$
is a subfield, then $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_q$ vectorspace, so it must have $q^m$ elements. But $p^n=q^m$ implies $p=q$

Comment: And to prove that $\mathbb{F}$ *does contain* $\mathbb{F}_q$ for some prime $q$, would this be correct: let $q:=\text{Char}(\mathbb{F})$, then we know $q$ is a prime, and $\{1,1+1,\ldots,1+1+\cdots+1\}$ (with $q$ elements) is a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{F}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: For any Ring $R$ there is a Homomorphism $\mathbb Z \rightarrow R$, which cannot be injective if $R$ is finite. If $R$ is a domain, then the kernel must be a prime ideal $(p)$.